# Using enum in Android Java programming

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to write a game in android and I want to use enum.

This is my enum class:

```
public enum State {
   INACTIVE(0), ACTIVE(1);

  private final int value;

  private State(int value){
      this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
      return value;
  }
}
```

and then I want to use enum in my method and constructor:

```
public FieldsGame(){
    Board = new char[BOARD_SIZE_VERTICAL][BOARD_SIZE_HORIZONTAL];
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE_VERTICAL; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE_HORIZONTAL; j++) {
            Board[i][j] = EMPTY_SPACE;
            BoardState[i][j] = State.INACTIVE.getValue();
        }
    }
}

public void clearBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE_VERTICAL; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < BOARD_SIZE_HORIZONTAL; j++) {
            Board[i][j] = EMPTY_SPACE;
            BoardState[i][j] = State.INACTIVE.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to launch my application it sais "Unfortunatelly, *application* has stopped."
I'm sure it is because of enum cause when I comment these two lines:

```
BoardState[i][j] = State.INACTIVE.getValue();
```

where I'm using enum, it works. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Check your logcat- it will give you the Exception that is causing your application to crash, which will tell you exactly what went wrong and where.

Comment: Which two lines are you talking about? Please post the relevant sections of your log.

Comment: enum return an int , are you  setting it to a char array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm trying to launch my application it says "Unfortunately,
>   application has stopped." I'm sure it is because of enum because when I
>   comment these two lines where I'm using enum, it works. Can somebody
>   help me, please?

then is probably because `BoardState` was never initialized, and you are trying to access a null object. Add

```
BoardState = new int[BOARD_SIZE_VERTICAL][BOARD_SIZE_HORIZONTAL];
```

before the for loop in `FieldsGame`.